# find text from tableA.[snippetOfText] in tableB.[completeText]

Tags: sql, sql-server

This should be very easy, but I'm brain farting and can't find the answer

I have tableA with one varchar column [snippetOfText]

and tableB with one text column [completeText]

sample data:

```
tableA.snippetOfText
Dog
Cat
Bear

tableB.comleteText
'The cat is hungry'
'The dog is hungry'
'The monkey eats'
```

I need to search tableB, looking for all instances of tableA.snippetOftext

So, in this case, I would get the top two rows from tableB (containing dog and cat)

Something like

```
Select * from tableB
where completeText like (select snippetOfText from tableA)
```

That won't work, but it's the general idea.!

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
select * 
from tableA a
join tableB b on b.completeText like '%'+a.snippet+'%'
```